# validate Regex in php

Tags: php, regex

How this regex works?

```
'/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*\s*@\s*[a-z0-9-]+(\s*\.\s*[a-z0-9-]+)*(\s*\.\s*[a-z]{2,6})/ie'
```

I got this regex on web, I use cheatsheet but could not understand it.

Comment: see here http://regex101.com/r/vV9vF4 the `Your regular expression explained` section

Comment: Everything you need: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ http://regex101.com http://debuggex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the @ symbol, that looks like validation for email addresses.

---

**Explanation:**

The white-space characters are set to `+`, between zero and unlimited. They are not necessary. What is necessary however is the `@` symbol and between 2 and 6 characters after a final `.` This is entirely indicative of an email address.

If I sent an email to `some guy @whatever.com`, perhaps a typo, I could simply strip the white-space before sending rather than spit out an error.

The addition of allowing white-spaces could also mean this is used for a **list of email addresses**. Note that with the global modifier, the following would match 4 email addresses with the regular expression:

```
apple@man.com, 
thatguy@something.org, 
holy@moly.com, 
regex@friends.net
```

Comment: I doubt it, all these possible white-space characters...

Comment: See my edit for an explanation.